# How to destroy or unset PHP session variables from chrome extension using AJAX call to the logout.php page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

logout.php

```
<?php
if((isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] !='')){
   session_start();

    print json_encode($_SESSION);
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();      
}
?>
```

This is my AJAX call to logout in chrome extension

```
$('#signout_button').on('click', function(){

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1/extension_server/logout.php',
      data:{action:'logout'},
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ "login_status" : 0, "profile_id" : null }, function() {
          $('#signout_button').css('display','none');
          $('#signin_button').css('display','block');
          $('#login_info').css('display','none');
        });
      }
    });

});
```

I am trying to logout from the server when i click on sign out button from chrome extension popup.
I am able to make the AJAX call and get the returned data. But when i echo the $_SESSION variable without destroying the session variables i am getting [] (empty array). 
The Session variables are not getting destroyed from AJAX call (When i include session_destroy() also). Am i doing anything wrong here?
 Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked whether the session id gets passed successfully with the request? (And why are you doing this from an extension in the first place?)

Comment: I am building a chrome extension to automate linkedin related tasks, i have a server which has linkedin OAuth signin. When the user signIn from extension, it redirects to the server side LinkedIn Oauth signin. After successful signin from Oauth, He is redirected back to linkedin page with his userId. Now i need to clear the Login session from the server when i click logout in my chrome extension. How can this be done? CBroe